# Xamarin How to load listView detail from Rest API based on id?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I have listview. when the item clicked, it will open detail page. But for performance issue, in restAPI I set it to only send the data needed on the listView. That's why I want to get new request to api based id which I have from clicked listview.

listview.xaml.cs:

```
        private async void OnItemSelected(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
        {
        var itemDetail = e.Item as Data.Models.ModelAttendance.Attendance;
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new ListDetailAttendPage
            (
                itemDetail.Id, itemDetail.Image, itemDetail.Created, itemDetail.AddressDetail,
                itemDetail.Note, itemDetail.Activity
            ));
        }
```

listViewDetail.xaml.cs

```
    private ObservableCollection<Data.Models.ModelAttendance.Attendance> _attendances;

    public ListDetailAttendPage (long id, byte[] image, DateTime created, string addressDetail, string note, string activity)
    {
        InitializeComponent ();

        long idItem = id;
        ImgSelfie.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(image));
        EntTime.Text = created.ToString();
        EdtLocation.Text = addressDetail;
        EntNote.Text = note;
        LblAction.Text = activity;

    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        _attendances = new ObservableCollection<Data.Models.ModelAttendance.Attendance>();
        base.OnAppearing();
    }
```

the API code that i use in listview page:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetM_ATTENDANCE()
    {
        var data = _context.M_ATTENDANCE.Select(f => new Attendance
        {
            Id = f.Id,
            Name = f.Name,
            Activity = f.Activity,
            Created = f.Created
        }).OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).ToList();

        var tempJson = new
        {
            Data = data,
            Size = data.Count
        };
        return Json(tempJson);
    }
```

How can I do that in xamarin.form ? I have searched but there is no right solution. This is what I have try, but I still can't get wanted data :

```
    private ObservableCollection<Data.Models.ModelAttendance.Attendance> _attendances;
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    public ListDetailAttendPage (long id, byte[] image, DateTime created, string addressDetail, string note, string activity)
    {
        InitializeComponent ();

        long idItem = id;
        ImgSelfie.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(image));
        EntTime.Text = created.ToString();
        EdtLocation.Text = addressDetail;
        EntNote.Text = note;
        LblAction.Text = activity;

        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await GetItem(idItem);
        });

    }

    async Task GetItem(long id)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage message = await client.GetAsync(string.Format("http://[url]:[port]/api/attendances/" + id));
        string jsonString = await message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

     //what should I do next to get the data here?

    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        _attendances = new ObservableCollection<Data.Models.ModelAttendance.Attendance>();
        base.OnAppearing();
    }
```

I already have rest API to get respons based on id, but dont know to use it in Xamarin :

```
        // GET: api/Attendances/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAttendance(long id)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        var attendance = await _context.M_ATTENDANCE.FindAsync(id);

        if (attendance == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(attendance);
    }
```

I just started learning xamarin, please ask me if my question is still not clear

your help is much appreciated ^_^

Comment: you need to deserialize `jsonString` into an object.

Comment: Can you please share the `jsonString`  here? Just need an example.

Comment: is this what you mean? @Jason
`var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);`

Comment: I mean something like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/W6J11.png).

Comment: How are you getting the data for the list view?  The process should be basically the same

Comment: [This](https://i.imgur.com/k0o2hJ4.png) is the response I got from jsonString @JackHua-MSFT

Comment: @Jason , I use MVVM in my listView, I cannot use same way because I haven't found a way to do it in MVVM, that's why I want to learn it in the form of xamarin.form code behind first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just deserialize `JSON string` into the class `Model`

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        testAsync();
    }

    public async Task testAsync() {

        string json = @"{
              'id': '123',
              'name': 'User name',
              'nik': '213123'
            }";

        Model m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model>(json);

        Console.WriteLine(m.name);
        Console.WriteLine(m.nik);

    }
}

public class Model
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string nik { get; set; }
    public string Created { get; set; }
}
```

**Update**: update UI in Main thread

```
  Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
                EdtLocation.Text = result.AddressDetail;
                //...
            });
```

Comment: I've tried based on the solution you suggest. thankfully I have managed to get the picture, but I dont know why the debug stop in [here](https://i.imgur.com/BtEev9Z.png) and I can't get the rest of the value? Any idea?

Comment: @Machtal Can you use  Console.WriteLine(result.AddressDetail); to check what is result.AddressDetail, is it null? What's the type of result.AddressDetail?

Comment: the [result.AddressDetail](https://i.imgur.com/L9wlH3p.png) is not null and the type is string

Comment: @Machtal Then it should work, it's the same like EdtLocation.Text = "abc";.

Comment: @Machtal Does it also stuck if you write directly like  EdtLocation.Text = "abc"; in that method?

Comment: @Machtal See my updated answer, try to update it in MainThread!

Comment: whooa....the problem was solved like a magic trick, thank you so much @JackHua-MSFT  :D

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT: I am very new to Xamarin. I have a similar problem. I am passing selected rowID as in this question, but my "async Task GetItem(long id)" method is inside my ViewModel class which invoke rest api to get the desired result. Data comes perfectly from rest api but it does not show up on view/page as the view gets loaded with blank data before api returns the value. What should I do? Second question is where should I write the piece of code "Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>" you suggested? Thanks

Comment: @Vijay You should use data binding to update data after the data comes back from your api. I would suggest you to open a new thread and add your relevant question and code there, then we will support you.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT: Thanks. I have opened a new thread "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62739541/xamarin-forms-load-a-detail-page-consuming-rest-api-onitemselected-of-listview". Please have a look. Waiting for your inputs.