# Xamarin Forms: Load a Detail page consuming REST API OnItemSelected of listview

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have listview. when the item is clicked, it will open a detail page to show detail information of selected item by taking selected item as a input parameter. To fetch the detail information I need to a REST api call. Once the response is received from api, I need to bind that information on the detail view/page.

listview.xaml.cs:

```
 async void OnItemSelected(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        var layout = (BindableObject)sender;
        var item = (Target)layout.BindingContext; // Passing to be used as input parameters value in API call.
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new TargetDetailPage(new TargetDetailViewModel(item)));
    }
```

TargetDetailPage.xaml:

```
    <ContentPage.Content>
    <RefreshView IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=TwoWay}"  Command="{Binding LoadTargetDetailCommand}">
        <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#f8f9fa" Orientation="Vertical" >
        <Label Text="{Binding Title}" x:Name="lblTitle" Padding="5,0,0,5" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" FontAttributes="Bold" />
        <Grid Padding="5"  ColumnSpacing="0" RowSpacing="5">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="50"  />
                <RowDefinition Height="30" />

            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <StackLayout Grid.Row="0"  Grid.Column="0"  BackgroundColor="#e9ecef"  >
                <Label Text="{Binding VerificationDetail.target_name, StringFormat='Use this phone number for {0}'}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"   />
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Grid.Row="0"  Grid.Column="1"  BackgroundColor="#e9efff"  >
                <Entry x:Name="txtNumber" Text="{Binding VerificationDetail.number}" ></Entry>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Grid.Row="1"  Grid.Column="0"  BackgroundColor="#e9ecef"  >
                <Label  Text="Verification Cost"   HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Grid.Row="1"  Grid.Column="1"  BackgroundColor="#e9ecef"  >
                <Label Text ="{Binding VerificationDetail.cost}"  HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"  Margin="0"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Grid.Row="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Button Grid.Column="0"  Text="Cancel" ></Button>
                    <Button Grid.Column="1"  Text="Report Number"></Button>
                </Grid>

            </StackLayout>

        </Grid>
    </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </RefreshView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

TargetDetailPage.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class TargetDetailPage : ContentPage
{
    TargetDetailViewModel viewModel;

    readonly int targetId;
    public TargetDetailPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public TargetDetailPage(TargetDetailViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = this.viewModel = viewModel;

    }
    public TargetDetailPage(int seledtedTargetId)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        targetId = seledtedTargetId;
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        if (viewModel.VerificationDetail == null)
            viewModel.IsBusy = true;

       
    }
}
```

TargetDetailViewModel .cs:

```
public class TargetDetailViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public VerificationDetail VerificationDetail { get; set; }

    public Target Target { get; set; }

    public Command LoadTargetDetailCommand { get; set; }

    public TargetDetailViewModel()
    {
        Title = "Verification Detail";
    }

    public TargetDetailViewModel(Target target)
    {
        Title = "Verification Detail";
        Target = target;
        LoadTargetDetailCommand = new Command(async () => await CreateVerification(target?.TargetId));
    }

    public async Task CreateVerification(int? targetId)
    {
        IsBusy = true;

        try
        {
            if (targetId.HasValue)
            {
                VerificationDetail = await DataStoreVerificationDetail.CreateVerification(targetId.Value);
                if (VerificationDetail != null && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(VerificationDetail.sms))
                {
                    VerificationDetail.sms = "Verification Detail.";
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            IsBusy = false;
        }
    }

}
```

DataStoreVerificationDetail.cs:

```
    public async Task<VerificationDetail> CreateVerification(int taregtId)
    {
        var token = App.bearer_token;
        Uri baseUri = new Uri(Constants.BaseURL);
        var uri = new Uri(baseUri, "Api/Verifications");

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient
        {
            MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 256000
        };

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {token}");
        var httpContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { id = taregtId }), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, httpContent);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var verificationDetail = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<VerificationDetail>(content);

            return verificationDetail; ;
        }
        return verificationDetail;


    }
```

**Edit:** My problem is Detail View does not show data received from api. A blank view is shown without data before the asyn api call completed.

Comment: When I call CreateVerification from OnAppearing of "TargetDetailPage.cs" like this " protected async override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            if (viewModel == null)
            {
                viewModel = new TargetDetailViewModel();

                await viewModel.CreateVerification(targetId);
                 BindingContext = viewModel;
", then it shows data as expected.

Comment: What is your question?  You have stated some requirements and pasted a LOT of code, but you haven't told us specifically what you need help with, or where you're having a problem.

Comment: Please, edit your question with some valuable information, what is your issue, what kind of errors you have, what does not work etc... In order to help you, we need a real question with an explanation. Thanks!

Comment: @Jason : Sorry for my mistake. I have edited my post. My problem is Detail View does not show data received from api. A blank view is shown without data before the asyn api call completed.

Comment: I don't see where you execute LoadTargetDetailCommand to load any data

Comment: @Jason: command gets executed inside constructor like LoadTargetDetailCommand = new Command(async () => await CreateVerification(target?.TargetId));

Comment: that creates the command, it does not actually execute it

Comment: Okay. Sorry I new and don't know much about xamarinforms.  On my details view I mentioned like "<RefreshView IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=TwoWay}"  Command="{Binding LoadTargetDetailCommand}"> ". Will this not execute command. If not then how can I execute the command. I have similar implementation on my listview page and shows data from api perfectly. Please guide. Thanks

Comment: @AlmirVuk: I have modified my question. Please guide how to resolve the issue. My problem is Detail View does not show data received from api. A blank view is shown without data before the async api call completed.